# Does CiviDiscount no longer work with new releases?

Tags: cividiscount

We are on WordPress 6.4.2 and  CiviCRM 5.69.2

We have used the CiviDiscont extension for years. Now it is no longer available to download and install through the extension manager. Also the existing install that we already had appears to be missing. It was never uninstalled or deleted, however clicking the link in the menu just takes us back to the CiviCRM homepage and I cannot find any trace of CiviDiscount anywhere on the CiviCRM install.

Answer (score 0):

*Jan 22, 2024, WordPress 6.4.2, Powered by CiviCRM 5.69.2, free and open source AGPLv3 software.*

[image: Before]

---

[image: After]

Please check CiviCRM (and the webserver) logs for oddities.